# DS201 Cassandra killrvideo - Python Driver and Nodes

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Environment: DSE DS201 VM

Error 1: 
Exercise 5 : Drivers.ipynb [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6fYj.png)

While trying to use the Python driver to connect to Cassandra.

```
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    cluster = Cluster()
    session = cluster.connect('killrvideo')

    NoHostAvailable    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-535660701145> in <module>()
    1 from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    2 cluster = Cluster()
    ----> 3 session = cluster.connect('killrvideo')

   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.so in     
    cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:11471)()
```

Error 2:
Exercise: 7 Ring.ipynb

Once I make the changes as suggested in the notebook and start the Node 1; face errors.

```
    root@sample:~/Desktop/node1/bin# ./cassandra
    Cannot change the number of tokens from 256 to 1
    Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
    ERROR 22:08:32 Fatal configuration error
```

org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot change the number of tokens from 256 to 1
...

Followed the Jupyter notebook throughly. Yet face an error.

Comment: What are the values for num_tokens and initial_token in your cassandra.yaml

Comment: As suggested in the notebook of the exercise, made changes as below:

num_tokens value from 256 to 1.

Uncomment the initial_token value and set it to 0.

listen_address from localhost to 127.0.0.1

in the cassandra-env.sh:

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="128M"
HEAP_NEW_SIZE"32M"

Comment: Since I was using the VM provided by DS, called DS201; seems it uses the drivers specific to DSE release.

So I finally installed the DSE drivers

        #pip install cassandra-driver-dse

        #python -c 'import dse; print dse.__version__'
        output should be : 1.0.2

After that I am able to connect to DS using Python

Answer (score 0):

So finally I resolved this. The issue was with the Python drivers